# Ebtables rule limit

Tags: firewall, centos7, ebtables

Does anyone have any idea about ebtables rule count limitations?
It starts giving this error around 26000 rules for filter table :

```
[root@localhost 09]# ebtables -A testchain1 -p IPv4 --ip-src 'ipv4.x.x.x' -s 'mac:x:x:x:x:x' -j ACCEPT
```

Unable to update the kernel. Two possible causes:

1. Multiple ebtables programs were executing simultaneously. The ebtables
   userspace tool doesn't by default support multiple ebtables programs running
   concurrently. The ebtables option --concurrent or a tool like flock can be
   used to support concurrent scripts that update the ebtables kernel tables.
2. The kernel doesn't support a certain ebtables extension, consider
   recompiling your kernel or insmod the extension.
   .
   [root@localhost 09]#

There is free RAM while SWAP is fully used.

Comment: Are you using an ancient and/or 32-bit kernel? (post the output of `uname -a`)

Comment: Linux localhost.servers.com **3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64** #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 **x86_64** GNU/Linux 
And 
**ebtables.x86_64 : 2.0.10-16.el7**